# Cant understand why $C_1$ and $C_1$ are in parallel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]

We need to find the equivalent capacitance in this question.

As in the solution on this website:
https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/take-c140mu-f-and-c260mu-f-in-the-figure-calculate-the-equivalent-capacitance-of-the/

C1 and C1 are in series.

But there is a wire between them, the thumb rule for series combination is that there should be only one path. So C1 and C1 should be in parallel as there is a bifurcation. I'm confused the rule of thumb isn't working here, is this an exception??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two C1's are not in series, for exactly the reason you say.

However, because C1 is equal to C1 and C2 is equal to C2, we can show by symmetry that, assuming we start with all capacitors discharged, no current flows through the middle wire, and therefore if we remove it the behavior of the circuit won't change.

Once we remove the middle wire, then the two C1's are in series and the two C2's are in series.

> So C1 and C1 should be in parallel as there is a bifurcation.

This is not correct.

For two parts to be in parallel, both of their ends must be connected, not just one end.

> ... the thumb rule for series combination is that there should be only one path. So C1 and C1 should be in parallel...

There is no rule that says if two parts are not in series they must be in parallel.

Comment: I understand that the wire in the middle is useless so we remove it to simplify the circuit. Thus, before we removed the wire in the middle. C1 and C1 are neither in parallel nor in series, correct?

Comment: @AkA_Ghost, correct.

Answer (score 0):

Being in parallel combination implies the elements of a circuit are connected between the same two nodes. Naming the left node as A, the middle node as B and the right node as C, $C_1$ is connected between A and B and the other $C_1$ is connected between B and C and hence both of these capacitors are end to end. Therefore they are in series and not parallel.
The above circuit is a Wheatstone bridge; hence no current passes through the middle wire, and it's redundant.